# Cannot record video+audio on iPhone Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, webrtc, recordrtc

I have used RecordRTC for capturing the video+audio from the browser. 
For Android devices, it's working perfectly as expected. But in iPhone devices especially on the safari browser, it's not recording as expected.

Browser console produces the following error.

`Your browser does not support Media Recorder API. Please try other modules e.g. WhammyRecorder or StereoAudioRecorder.`

Could someone please help me out like:
Does Safari support basic video capturing?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use StereoAudioRecorder which is made in RecordRTC.js as Recorder for *Safari*.

This is the document of StereoAudioRecorder.
You're going to have to read this first :)

https://recordrtc.org/StereoAudioRecorder.html

```
const option = {
  type: 'video',
  recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder
};
const recorder = new RecordRTC(mic, options);

recorder.startRecording();
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information but StereoAudioRecorder is creating the only Audio File.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder

MediaRecorder was introduced in iOS14 (Safari 14), if you have an older version, this can be your problem.

Comment: It's better to at least suggest other ways to implement that feature. or leave a comment

Comment: I couldn't find any other way, sorry